# Getting undefined index 'uploadedfile' at php side while uploading pdf file with parameter from android

Tags: php, android, file-upload, parameter-passing

i am creating an application in which i want to upload file to php side from android application. if i am comment parameter code then file upload successful and if i comment file upload code from php page then parameter pass successfuly. please help me.
following is my php code.

```
$flag=$_POST['f'];
$file_path = "upload/";

$file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);


if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $file_path))
{
   echo "successfully upload";
}
else
{
   echo "fail to upload";
}
echo $flag;
```

following my android code.

```
cn.setDoInput(true);
cn.setDoOutput(true);
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("f", "jeet"));
OutputStream os = cn.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
writer.write(getQuery(params));
writer.flush();
writer.close();
os.close();
//  cn.setUseCaches(false);
cn.setRequestMethod("POST");
cn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");

cn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
cn.setRequestProperty("uploadedfile", m_chosen); 
cn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","multipart/form-data;boundary="    +boundary);
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(cn.getOutputStream());
dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: post-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\""+ m_chosen + "\"" + lineEnd);
dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
```

Comment: That is a strange mixture at wrting data at two different places with two streams. The biggest sin though is closing the stream there.

Comment: then what should i do to solve the problem?

Comment: You should Google this site for example ode. Such code has been posted here many times.